# Another rows merging in MySQL [+php?]

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I merge a row with existing one instead of inserting it, if there is empty fields in existing rows?

Here an example. Existing rows:

```
id    f1    f2    f3    f4    ...
0     a           b     
1     c
```

Row to insert:

```
id    f1    f2    f3    f4    ...
NULL        d
```

Needed result:

```
id    f1    f2    f3    f4    ...
0     a     d     b     
1     c
```

I've made a PHP function for this, which `SELECTS` empty rows for each field and updates data in this rows, but this is too slow. Is there any way to improve and speed-up this code?

```
foreach($cond as $cond_name = > $cond_value) {
    if ($cond_value != '') {
        $cond_count++;
        $q = 'SELECT `id` FROM `g_ul_cond_orders` WHERE `ul_id`='.$ul_id.' AND `'.$cond_name.'`="" LIMIT 1;';
        $r = mysql_query($q);
        if ($r) {
            if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
                $q = 'UPDATE `g_ul_cond_orders` SET `'.$cond_name.'`="'.$cond_value.'" WHERE `id`='.$row['id'].';';
                $r = mysql_query($q);
                if ($r) {
                    $cond[$cond_name] = '';
                    $cond_count--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least you can use one query for the updates

```
UPDATE `g_ul_cond_orders` SET `'.$cond_name.'`="'.$cond_value.'" WHERE `id`= (SELECT `id` FROM `g_ul_cond_orders` WHERE `ul_id`='.$ul_id.' AND `'.$cond_name.'`="" LIMIT 1);
```

With this query the second query and result in your code wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Oh, simple.. just didn't think about that. Thank you. in this case time is decreased because data is transfering only once. And it will not update table, if SELECT returns empty result. Best deal for now

Comment: Yep, almost 8 times faster. Just checked it out.

Comment: Haha.. It is so fast because it is not working. I'm sorry i didn't made intended testing, so there is error in query.

Comment: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'g_ul_cond_orders' for update in FROM clause`

There is an ugly workaround about that.. Working query is `UPDATE g_ul_cond_orders AS o, (SELECT id FROM g_ul_cond_orders WHERE ul_id='.$ul_id.' AND '.$cond_name.' IS NULL LIMIT 1) i SET '.$cond_name.'="'.$cond_value.'" WHERE o.id= i.id;`

Now it is even slower than mine, so i'll switch back to my first code. You don't mind if i reopen the question?

Comment: I've read about the error, it occurs in nested queries like my example. Then if you examine the query in my example you can see that the nested (SELECT) query is also unnecessary.
So it should be 

UPDATE `g_ul_cond_orders` SET `'.$cond_name.'`="'.$cond_value.'" WHERE `ul_id`='.$ul_id.' AND `'.$cond_name.'`="" LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with what's known generically as an "upsert" - in mySQL you can do it with the ["INSERT..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax

Comment: Sorry, but upserting is not an option, because the only key of this table is id, and i don't know yet if there is any "empty spots" in table grid to insert field data. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: It should work if, as it appears in your php code sample, you know the id, and can include it in the insert. If you don't know that, then how would you know which row you're merging into in any case?

Comment: i meant that i don't know the id before executing this code. Well yes, after select i know the id and yes, it seems to be possible to upsert the row with something like `INSERT INTO g_ul_cond_orders (id,f1,f2) VALUES(found_id,f1_val,f2_val) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET f1=VALUES(f1) ...`, but i don't think it will be faster, than my code..